# While I was washing utensils in the kitchen, my mother relaxed/was relaxing

Tags: past-tense

While I was washing utensils in the kitchen, my mother ________(relaxed/was relaxing) on the sofa.
Which one is correct relaxed or was relaxing?

Is it okay to combine past continuous tense (was washing) with a simple past tense (relaxed) or must the whole sentence be in past continuous tense?

Comment: Either is correct, but 'washing utensils' sounds unidiomatic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I only need to change relaxed or was relaxing, the 'washing utensils' thing is part of the question.

Comment: @SujalMotagi They are both grammatical. If this is from a test, then there is insufficient information provided to know why it thinks only one is correct.

Comment: The fact that a test contains '[While I was] washing utensils in the kitchen' indicates that it might well have a dubious marking scheme.

Comment: I would have a slight preference for "was relaxing" because then the tenses of the words match, but both are acceptable. If they say that "relaxed" is wrong then I think that their argument is quite weak. If they say that "was relaxing" is wrong I'd love to know why.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm frankly quite puzzled as to why you would consider *washing utensils* "unidiomatic".  Certinaly, in Britain at least, we would talk of "doing the washing-up", but there are plenty of circumstances I can think of where someone might say "I'm washing (the) utensils" - in a laboratory, for example.

Comment: @WS2 The original here is 'While I was washing utensils in the kitchen, my mother ... on the sofa.' In the context given, it sounds unidiomatic. _Of course_ there are occasions when it might be used and sound more natural. But standalone as used here, it sounds unnatural, and over-precise. As you hint, 'washing up' is more to be expected, at least in the UK. Perhaps a broadened use of 'doing the dishes' in the US.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Your concern seemed to me to be exclusively with the vocabulary - i.e. use of the word "utensils" in connection with "kitchen" and "sofa" - not with the past continuous (or the imperfect as I would call it) followed by the simple past. Would you have felt happier had they been called "cooking utensils"?

Comment: @WS2 I believe that when I wrote the 'comments', the question was still on ELU.  ELL is not a site I visit at all regularly. I believe it's correct to address concerns such as register on ELU (I wouldn't have considered the question suitable for a site aimed at linguists rather than those mastering the basics. Would you?)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I've no idea. It was just that your saying "'washing utensils' sounds unidiomatic" struck me as odd - since it sounds perfectly idiomatic to me.

Comment: @WS2 Even '... washing cooking utensils ...' sounds overly precisionist here to my ears. 'While I was in the kitchen washing knives and forks but not spoons, my mother relaxed on the red and ivory sofa.' is another example of what I would consider a contrived sentence. Totally grammatical, but unnatural-sounding.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth How about if you'd been doing something unusual, like e.g. icing a cake, or doing some pottery, and were using  special "utensils" that didn't have a clear collective name? After all, what is a utensil? Google dictionary says "a tool, container or other article for household use". And it gives as an example "kitchen utensils". Like you I might well never use the term, but I have no trouble grasping why someone else might do so.

Comment: @WS2 'Like you, I might well never use the term' and the default definition of 'idiomatic' ('typical of the natural way in which someone speaks or writes when they are using their own language') ([Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/idiomatic)) don't match, in my idiolect. Out of licensing context (as here), I find it strange. A string I will probably never use. I was trying to say to the OP that 'washing up' would sound far more natural here. Not an answer to the question, just general help.

Answer (score 1):

These are both acceptable, but they have a very slight difference in meaning. The continuous sense tends to focus on the process... making it seem like it takes time. So saying I 'was washing' helps the hearer get the idea of the time it took.

So what you want to do with the mother depends on whether you want to emphasize the time (was relaxing) or the state (relaxed).

The most natural is probably to put them in parallel: thus "While I washed... relaxed' or 'While I was washing... was relaxing'.

Comment: I don't think that there is any preference for aligning the tenses in general